# How to choose bucket length in Spark's Bucketed Random Projection?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hash

How should I optimally choose bucket length in Spark's LSH algorithm [Bucketed Random Projection](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#bucketed-random-projection-for-euclidean-distance)?

It is this parameter set with .setBucketLength(), e.g. from the Spark documentation:

```
  val brp = new BucketedRandomProjectionLSH()
  .setBucketLength(2.0)
  .setNumHashTables(3)
  .setInputCol("keys")
  .setOutputCol("values")
```

Any theoretical references that support the choice of bucket length would be appreciated.

The only suggestion I was able to find on the Web was [this one](https://vinta.ws/code/spark-ml-cookbook-scala.html), which does not explain the choice of the chosen heuristics.

> To specify the value of bucketLength, if input vectors are normalized, 1-10 times of pow(numRecords, -1/inputDim) would be a reasonable value.

Therefore I am not really sure why that heuristics is supposed to work in general.

Comment: actually this quoted sentence comes from official scala doc. link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.BucketedRandomProjectionLSHModel@bucketLength:org.apache.spark.ml.param.DoubleParam . try to expand the `bucketLength` parameter for detail

Comment: I found a nice explanation at this link: https://george-jen.gitbook.io/data-science-and-apache-spark/locality-sensitive-hashing